# RateLimitIntervalSec and RateLimitBurst in journald.conf are not working at all

Tags: ubuntu, centos7, systemd, journald

I am trying to see how log drop count in the `journald` works. In the `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file, I modified `RateLimitIntervalSec` to 1 second and the `RateLimitBurst` to 2 so that I can see some logs getting dropped if I restart one systemd units(I picked `thermald.service` that throws at least >5 logs in a second). After making this change, I did `systemctl force-reload systemd-journald` so that it picks the latest journald configuration.

The `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` file looks like below:

```
[Journal]
#Storage=auto
#Compress=yes
#Seal=yes
#SplitMode=uid
#SyncIntervalSec=5m
RateLimitIntervalSec=1s
RateLimitBurst=2
#SystemMaxUse=
#SystemKeepFree=
#SystemMaxFileSize=
#SystemMaxFiles=100
#RuntimeMaxUse=
#RuntimeKeepFree=
#RuntimeMaxFileSize=
#RuntimeMaxFiles=100
#MaxRetentionSec=
#MaxFileSec=1month
#ForwardToSyslog=yes
#ForwardToKMsg=no
#ForwardToConsole=no
#ForwardToWall=yes
#TTYPath=/dev/console
#MaxLevelStore=debug
#MaxLevelSyslog=debug
#MaxLevelKMsg=notice
#MaxLevelConsole=info
#MaxLevelWall=emerg
#LineMax=48K
```

I restarted `thermald.service`, still `journalctl -u thermald` shows all the logs around restart and no logs getting dropped as such. I even restarted the machine just to double sure `journald.conf` changes get freshly applied, but still the same issue.

This is the set of logs I see in everytime I restart thermald. It's evident that no logs are getting dropped.

```
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm systemd[1]: Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm systemd[1]: Started Thermal Daemon Service.
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: NO RAPL sysfs present
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: 22 CPUID levels; family:model:stepping 0x6:8e:a (6:142:10)
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: Polling mode is enabled: 4
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: Thermal DTS: No coretemp sysfs found
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: Thermal DTS or hwmon: No Zones present Need to configure manually
Oct 05 12:43:30 pineapplet-vm thermald[1690]: No thermal sensors found
lines 15-61/61 (END)
```

I am not sure what is wrong. I have tested it on other systemd units as well with no luck. How do I test log drop count feature of journald? Please help.

Tried on: CentOs 7 and Ubuntu 18.10

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem  might be that you need to run the command

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

**before** restarting the service.